# Providing answers to questions that will obviously be closed

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, policy

I've noticed a couple of questions recently that obviously were not questions fitting our format (because they are not asking for software recommendations) and thus were later closed/put on hold (all good so far).

However before closing some users (not new users, people with decent rep, and sometimes users who are also on the list voting to close the question) are submitting answers - despite that the questions obviously are not asking for software recommendations, and the respective answers to said questions are also obviously not software recommendations. Furthermore these answers are then receiving upvotes.

According to our help on [How do I write a good answer?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) we are told:

> Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...
>
> - ...are not about software recommendations as defined in the help center.

Examples:

- [Software licence giving full non-profit use](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11125/software-licence-giving-full-non-profit-use)
- [Which can OCR better: scanner or software?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10793/which-can-ocr-better-scanner-or-software)

Have the rules about answering questions that don't fit the site changed and I missed the memo? If not, why are people a) answering questions that aren't asking for software recommendations (especially when they vote to close it) and b) upvoting answers that are obviously not software recommendations?

Comment: Related (about SO): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/closing-etiquette-why-do-some-answer-and-close

Answer (score 5):

Don't answer questions that you think should be closed and can't be salvaged.
Answering is wasting one's time.

For the license question, I guess that Izzy just felt generous and wanted to exceptionally help that particular person who is working for a non-profit.

For the OCR question, a physical scanner actually also contains software, so I guess it was not 100% obvious that it is off-topic.